# Firebase Authenticate on IOS using a Phone Number - [auth/internal-error]

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I made a code in ionic to authenticate using a phone number in firebase, on the web and on android it works perfectly, the behavior on ios is different when I try to call a method to send the OTP.

```
   let recpVerify = new RecaptchaVerifier(name, {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response: any) => {
      }
    }, authentication);

    signInWithPhoneNumber(authentication, '+' + window.localStorage.getItem("phone"), recpVerify)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
```

[auth/internal-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG1wg.png)

[auth/internal-error debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NY0q.png)

The only message I was able to get is "auth/internal-error". Apparently I did all the settings as described but without success, looking at all the posts seems to have a problem when using the RecaptchaVerifier component where it cannot be rendered on ios, I tried some solutions such as capacitor-firebase-auth, without success.

The question is, is there any solution to this? It is not possible for it to work for other platforms and only for ios have this problem.

Comment: Same here. Have you been able to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ernesto, not yet :(

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the similar error. Anyone found anything for it  Luiz Fernando, @ErnestoVallejoGarcía ?